# 1NF - 3NF deal with functional dependency. What does BCNF - 5NF deal with?

Tags: database-normalization

I read somewhere that 1NF - 3NF deal with functional dependency, and that the Higher Normal Forms focus on another aspect of database relationships, but I can't remember what. Does anyone know the answer to this?

1NF - 3NF deal with function dependency. BCNF - 5NF deal with **______**?

My best educated guess is non-tivial / multivalued dependencies.

Is that correct, or am I way off base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BCNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form) deals with functional dependencies.

[4NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form) deals with multivalued dependencies.

[5NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_normal_form) deals with join dependencies. [6NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form) deals with join dependencies in a more general way.